# Protect Tensorflow acos function from nans in Keras loss

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Suppose you have a Keras loss function with an acos inside and you want to protect the acos from invalid values (values outside `[-1,1]`). I.e., set < -1 to -1 and > 1 to 1.
How can you do this?

---

I've thought about using `tf.cond`, but I'm not sure how to correctly apply it:

```
def loss(y_true, y_pred):
    # typically in [-1,1], but maybe slightly smaller/larger than that due to num precision
    unprotected_acos_input = ... # shape: [batchsize]
    shape = unprotected_acos_input.shape[0]

    cond_low = tf.constant(-1, shape=[shape], dtype="float32")
    cond_high = tf.constant(1, shape=[shape], dtype="float32")

    protected_acos_input = tf.cond(tf.greater_equal(unprotected_acos_input, cond_low), lambda: unprotected_acos_input, lambda: tf.constant(-1, shape=[shape], dtype="float32"))
    # same for cond_high

    loss = tf.acos(protected_acos_input)
    return loss
```

This would set **all** acos inputs to 1 or -1 if just one value of the batch is outside of [-1,1]. How can I change only the item of the acos_input that is outside the range and not all of the items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `K.clip(unprotected_acos_input, -1, 1)`.

```py
>> a = np.linspace(-1.01, 1.01, 20)
array([-1.01      , -0.90368421, -0.79736842, -0.69105263, -0.58473684,
       -0.47842105, -0.37210526, -0.26578947, -0.15947368, -0.05315789,
        0.05315789,  0.15947368,  0.26578947,  0.37210526,  0.47842105,
        0.58473684,  0.69105263,  0.79736842,  0.90368421,  1.01      ])

>> K.eval(tf.acos(K.variable(a)))
array([       nan, 2.69909317, 2.49371832, 2.33374068, 2.19535195,
       2.06965208, 1.95207246, 1.83981909, 1.73095382, 1.62397929,
       1.51761336, 1.41063884, 1.30177357, 1.1895202 , 1.07194058,
       0.9462407 , 0.80785197, 0.64787434, 0.44249948,        nan])

>> K.eval(tf.acos(K.clip(K.variable(a), -1, 1)))
array([3.14159265, 2.69909317, 2.49371832, 2.33374068, 2.19535195,
       2.06965208, 1.95207246, 1.83981909, 1.73095382, 1.62397929,
       1.51761336, 1.41063884, 1.30177357, 1.1895202 , 1.07194058,
       0.9462407 , 0.80785197, 0.64787434, 0.44249948, 0.        ])
```

Comment: Just as a note for future readers: don't use this as is in a loss function with acos, since acos(1) or acos(-1) leads to a inf gradient. You have to add an epsilon to it.